# An abelian group $G$ that has order 216, but $6G$ has order 6

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I’m trying to prove the following statement: “if G is a finite abelian group with $|G|=216$ and $|6G|=6$, then determine $G$ up to isomorphism.”

I know that by the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, $G$ can be written as $\prod_{i=1}^{r}\mathbb{Z}_{n_i}$, where $\prod_{i=1}^{r}n_i=216$. How would I approach this problem?

Comment: You could try every possible sequence of $n_i$. You can economise on the work by remembering there is such a decomposition with $n_1\mid n_2\mid n_3\cdots$.

Comment: And from $|6G|=6$ it follows that $n_i\leq36$ for all $i$.